# MVC и ООП это одно и тоже?

Tags: php, веб-программирование, ооп, mvc

MVC и ООП это одно  и тоже? объясните пожалуйста.

Comment: Краткий ответ - **нет**.

Comment: ООП - способ организации и структурирования данных, MVC - части приложения, которые играют каждый свою роль, одна для визуализации данных, другая для управления этими данными и т.д.

Comment: мета-комментарий: вопрос выглядит всеобъемлющим, но закрывать его не стоит. Достаточно краткий обзорный ответ со ссылками для дальнейшего чтения дать. [Вот обсуждение на Мета](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/271/23044).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Нет**

**MVC** - это шаблон проектирования, который распределяет ответственнось между участками кода. Модель занимается данными, представление занимается отображением, контроллер занимается управлением. MVC может быть реализован на чем угодно - функция, объектах - это не имеет значения, имеет значение, кто чем занят в иерархии.

**ООП** - это общая парадигма программирования. ООП подразумевает, что задачи будут реализованы, представлены и решены с помощью и в виде объектов, что при вычислении счета в ресторане мы будем оперировать объектами, которые представляют из себя блюда. Функциональное программирование, в то же время, использовало бы другой подход, оперируя списком блюд.

MVC может быть реализован в парадигме ООП, равно как и в любой другой парадигме программирования.

Comment: Учитель, mvc, это не шаблон, а мульти-шаблон. ООП, это абстракция, лучшие реализации которой иллюстрируют паттернами.
По этому вопрос не является уж настолько и глупым, чтобы минусовать, ведь mvc является одной из лучших иллюстраций ооп.

Вы меня простите что я вмешиваюсь, но я уже не в первый раз читаю Ваши посты о mvc и мне кажется что Вы говорите о одной из самых плохих реализаций, где бизнес логика содержится в контролере.. Это так или мне кажется, где у Вас логика?

Comment: @shatal, я не очень понимаю, как MVC иллюстрирует ООП в условиях отсутствия приязки MVC к ООП и в эм отсутствии иллюстрируемого вообще. Бизнес-логика должна быть в модели, но практические реализации часто натыкаются на разного рода проблемы в том, чтобы запихнуть все в модель.

Comment: А я пока не знаком с языком, в котором нет объектов... Что это за языки такие?

Comment: @shatal самые класические пример - Lisp, С, еще есть Haskell, например; на PHP, Python, Ruby можно писать внутри парадигмы ФП. ООП много чем хорошо, но ресурсы и вправду жрет только в путь, поэтому спрос на ФП далеко не только академический.

Comment: Объект в программировании — некоторая сущность в виртуальном пространстве, обладающая определённым состоянием и поведением, имеющая заданные значения свойств (атрибутов) и операций над ними (методов)[1].   В приведенных Вами языках такого нет? Вот если бы я утверждал то, что утверждаете Вы, Вы бы смогли убедить меня в том, что в этих языках присутствует ооп?

Comment: @shatal я не очень понимаю вопрос, но в сишке действительно нет объектов. В сишке нет сущностей, у которых есть поведение (методы). Лисп трогал только в связи с SICP, хаскелл не трогал вообще, но уверен, что и там нет. И да, наличие объектов в языке не означает, что на нем можно писать только в парадигме ООП.

Comment: Я это говорю к том, что если паттерны являются лучшей иллюстрацией ооп, то язык который в состоянии реализовать паттерны можно назвать объектно ориентированным.  Вот например выписка из вики о lisp, она доказывает мои слова.  https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF#.D0.9E.D0.B1.D1.8A.D0.B5.D0.BA.D1.82.D0.BD.D0.BE-.D0.BE.D1.80.D0.B8.D0.B5.D0.BD.D1.82.D0.B8.D1.80.D0.BE.D0.B2.D0.B0.D0.BD.D0.BD.D0.BE.D0.B5_.D0.BF.D1.80.D0.BE.D0.B3.D1.80.D0.B0.D0.BC.D0.BC.D0.B8.D1.80.D0.BE.D0.B2.D0.B0.D0.BD.D0.B8.D0.B5

Comment: @shatal, нет. Во-первых, непонятно откуда взято утверждение о том, что паттерны обязательно связаны с ООП, во-вторых, "возможность реализовать что-то объектно-ориентированное" не является доказательством ООП-направленности языка.

Comment: И по поводу контроллера и модели, раз уж тема о mvc. Контроллер служит связующим звеном между пользователем, коем является представление, так как это единственный участник с которым может взаимодействовать пользоватль и моделью. Контроллер не может изменять модель, так как модель это само приложение и только она знает как ей нужно изменятся. Так нужно понять, что раз модель является приложением, то она должна полноценно работать в отрыве от других членов мульти-паттерна. Модель должна содержать только то, без чего не будет самого приложения.

Comment: @shatal, я сказал все, что хотел, и в этих словах я уверен процентов на девяносто. У меня действительно есть пробемы в описании парадигмы, скажем, но во всем остальном я уверен, точку зрения не изменю и не хочу писать еще раз. Можете считать меня роботом, если хотите.

Answer (score 5):

**НЕТ**

ООП (Объектно-ориентированная парадигма) - это модель описания предметной области, то есть как вы описываете предметную область компьютеру. Мы можем например смоделировать некоторую область как систему функций (ФП), или как некие действия (процедуры) изменяющие состояния каких-либо переменных (ПП), либо как некие объекты обменивающиеся сообщениями и взаимодействующие друг с другом (собственно ООП). Эти модели воплощаются в конкретных языках программирования.

MVC (Model-View-Controler) - это модель описания программного продукта (или если хотите шаблон), она диктует какие "детали" должна содержать ваша программа.