# Шаблоны для организации архитектуры приложения

Tags: ооп, шаблоны-проектирования

Есть `PHP OOP` и `MVC` - как это называется, верно?
И какие виды вот этого ещё бывают кроме `MVC`?

Comment: Вероятно вы имеете в виду паттерны ООП?

Comment: да наверно , какие ещё бывают ?

Comment: Может после прочтения сможете уточнить вопрос http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/423178/mvc-%D0%B8-%D0%9E%D0%9E%D0%9F-%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B8-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5

Comment: cache по ссылке нету того что мне нужно , то что OOP и MVC разное я понимаю , мне хотелось бы узнать что бывает ещё кроме MVC ?

Comment: Тогда, скорее всего, Вас интересуют MVC, MVP, MVVM подробнее на всемогущем хабре https://habrahabr.ru/post/215605/

Comment: cache ваш комментарий правильный , я понял что это называется паттерн ,это так ?

Comment: MVC - паттерн, ООP - парадигма

Comment: Паттерн или Шаблон. MVC, MVP, MVVM - это архитектурные шаблоны. синглетон, фасад, репозиторий, фабрика - это шаблоны проектирования. но они из несколько другой оперы.

Comment: С [википедии](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern) лучше начать. И по списку литературы. Большинство есть в переводе.

Comment: Yura Ivanov спс

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Паттернов очень много (синглтон, фасад, репозиторий, фабрика, прототип, мост, компоновщик, декоратор и т.д.), их так много, что они делятся на группы (структурные, порождающие, поведенческие и т.п.).

Например, MVC - архитектурный (или структурный) паттерн, синглтон - порождающий.

Сам термин заимствован из архитектуры зданий и предназначен для обозначений типовых решений в объектно-ориентированном программировании (в последнее время не только в нем, например, в базах данных).

Имеется немало книг, посвященных паттернам, лучшие переведены на русский язык. Самая известная - "Приёмы объектно-ориентированного проектирования. Паттерны проектирования" банды четверых, Ричард Хелм, Ральф Джонсон, Джон Влиссидс). Очень глубокие труды у Фаулера. Если вы только знакомитесь с темой, можно найти замечательное издание "Паттерны проектирования"  Эрик Фримен, Элизабет Фримен из серии Head First. Можно посоветовать [Game Programming Patterns](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com).

Тема очень большая, и осветить даже часть паттернов в одном ответе не получится, лучше спрашивайте про каждый конкретный паттерн отдельным вопросом.

Comment: cheops , это я так понимаю что MVC и то что вы перечислили это одно и тоже , ну в смысле можно написать так : mvc , синглетон , фасад, фабрика , мост - и это будет верно ?

Comment: mvc - архитектурный паттерн, singleton - creational паттерн, а так - да, их можно все в одну коробку свалить, конечно, но не рекомендуется

Comment: вот я как раз и хотел узнать - какие бывают ещё архитектурные патерны ?

Comment: @LenovoID Да, в первом приближении это все паттерны, но MVC во-первых два разных типа (Model I и Model II), а во-вторых, когда мы говорим о Web (а это Model II), можно утверждать, что MVC - это составной паттерн: Наблюдатель+Стратегия+Компоновщик.

Comment: а кроме mvc ещё бывает что то ? или он единственный ?

Comment: @LenovoID для таких вопросов я рекомендую вам делать например `google://mvc pattern vs` и гугл даст вам подсказку. еще пример `google://programming oop vs ...`

Comment: @LenovoID, бывает - их очень много. На самом деле это краткие обозначения архитектурных решений. Как со зданиями, когда вам говорят небоскреб, высотка, загородный котедж, вы не вдаваясь в пространные объяснения понимаете о каком типе жилья идет речь, о его цене, достоинствах, недостатках, времени на возведение. Точно так же и тут, когда говорят MVC, вы понимаете, что там внутри есть модели, контроллер и представления. Паттерны емко и кратко обозначают типовое решение.

Comment: я почти так писал но всегда вываливается только mvc

Comment: @LenovoID Начните с книги Фримен - там MVC в конце :) Зато очень подробное и юморное введение в предмет.

Comment: лан ,я скачал 6 книг по это тематике , буду читать спасибо